# Unable to start the sql server

Tags: sql-server

Someone set the sql server's memory very low and now I am unable to start the sql server.

Please give me some solution on how to start the SQL Server now.

Comment: What error message did you get? And when you say `very low`, what exactly do you mean? Oh, and did you sic the dogs on "someone" yet?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40481/accidentally-turned-down-sql-memory-too-low-to-log-in-how-do-i-fix

Comment: SQL Server Service is starting but when I open the SSMS it gives me the following error:

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)